# Pre-made delegates for operators?

Tags: c#

Supposing I want to use the addition operator (`+`) as a delegate, how would I pass that to a method?

Looking for something similar to Python's [`operator.add`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/library/operator.html#operator.add).

e.g., instead of

```
var center = _drawingPoly.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)/_drawingPoly.Count;
```

I'd want to write something like:

```
var center = _drawingPoly.Aggregate(operator+)/_drawingPoly.Count;
```

(FYI, `+` is overloaded here)

Comment: If a overloads that operator the overload is used instead

Comment: @BlackBear: Yes.....that's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you could do it using expression trees:

```
public static Func<T, T, T> OpAdd<T>()
{
    var param1Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var param2Expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var addExpr = Expression.Add(param1Expr, param2Expr);
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(addExpr, param1Expr, param2Expr);

    return expr.Compile();
}
```

which you can then use like:

```
var center = _drawingPoly.Aggregate(OpAdd<int>())/_drawingPoly.Count;
```

unfortunately this approach isn't type-safe, and you'll probably want to cache the resulting delegates that are created.

Comment: @Mark - You'll have to type them as `Delegate` or `object` and cast them when returning from the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, the language doesn't have such a feature.